# Django background tasks - problem with process_tasks

Tags: python, django

I have a strange case and don't know how to solve it. Namely I have installed Django background tasks, made a migration and added to installed aps.
I run python manage.py process_tasks in the terminal, open a second terminal and runserver. Everything is ok. In the admin panel I see: Completed Tasks and Tasks.
The first terminal listens all the time for the execution of the task and when I let it go it works perfectly. However, if I enter Completed Tasks or Tasks in Admin while the task is running, the first terminal immediately stops listening and goes back to waiting for the prompt.
Anyone perhaps know what this is all about?